How to derive this equation for $e^z- (1+z/n)^n$

$$e^z=\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n/n!$$


For all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac zn\right)^n =e^z.$$

I know there many ways to prove this  but I want to understand the answer provided by the book

For the first part of the exercise use the identity
$$
\exp z-\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^n=\frac{z}{n}\left(\frac{\exp (z / n)-1}{z / n}-1\right) \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1} \exp \left(\frac{z}{n}\right)^{n-1-\nu}\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^\nu,
$$
which immediately gives the estimate
$$
\left|\exp z-\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^n\right| \leq|z|\left|\frac{\exp (z / n)-1}{z / n}-1\right| \exp |z| .
$$
The involved quotient converges to the derivative of exp at 0 , which is 1 . The whole expression then converges to 0 .

I don't know how to derive the first equity or where the second inequality came from.
I tried to use binomial theorem on  $(1+z/n)^n$ and the definition of $e^z$ provided by the book (Taylor series) but I didn't reach the equality.

Do you know the sum of a geometric progression?

Here is a partial answer:
\begin{align}
\sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1}\exp^{n-1-\nu}\left(\frac zn\right)\left(1+\frac zn\right)^\nu
&=\exp^{n-1}\left(\frac zn\right)\sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1+\frac zn}{\exp\left(\frac zn\right)}\right)^\nu\\
&=\exp^{n-1}\left(\frac zn\right)\frac{1-\left(\frac{1+z/n}{\exp\left(z/n\right)}\right)^n}{1-\frac{1+z/n}{\exp\left( z/n\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\exp^n\left(\frac zn\right)}{\exp\left(\frac zn\right)}\cdot\frac{1-\frac{\left(1+z/n\right)^n}{\exp z}}{1-\frac{1+z/n}{\exp\left(z/n\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\exp z}{\exp\left(\frac zn\right)}\cdot\frac{1-\frac{\left(1+z/n\right)^n}{\exp z}}{1-\frac{1+z/n}{\exp\left(z/n\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\exp(z)-\left(1+\frac zn\right)^n}{\exp\left(\frac zn\right)-1-\frac zn}\\
&=\frac{\exp(z)-\left(1+\frac zn\right)^n}{\frac zn\left(\frac{\exp\left(z/n\right)-1}{z/n}-1\right)}.
\end{align}

Here is another method for OP's question.
Let
$$R_n(z)=\left|\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{z^k}{k!}\right|,\quad \forall z\in\mathbb C$$
then
\begin{aligned}
R_n(z) 
&=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}\left(\frac{z}{n}\right)^k- \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{z^k}{k!}\right|\\
&=\left|\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{z^k}{k!}\left[\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}-1\right]\right|
\quad\text{(the terms $k=0,1$ are cancelled)} \\
&= \left|\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{z^k}{k!}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n}\cdots\frac{n-k+1}{n}-1\right)\right| \\
&= \left|\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{z^k}{k!} \left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot \left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)-1\right]\right| \\
&\leq\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{|z|^k}{k!}\left[1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot \left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\right]\\
&\leq\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{|z|^k}{k!}\left(\frac1n+\frac2n+\cdots+\frac{k-1}n\right) \quad(*)\\
&=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{|z|^k}{(k-2)!}\\
&\leq\frac{1}{2n}|z|^2e^{|z|},
\end{aligned}
where $(*)$ we use general version of Bernoulli's inequality:

For any $a_1,\cdots a_n>-1$, having all the same sign, we have
$$(1+a_1)\dotsm(1+a_n)\ge 1+a_1+\dots+a_n.$$

So $R_n(z)$ is uniformly convergent to $0$ on compact $K\subset\mathbb C$.
Hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac zn\right)^n
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{z^k}{k!}
=e^z,\quad \forall z\in\mathbb C.$$

To get the rest of the estimate:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1} \exp \left(\frac{z}{n}\right)^{n-1-\nu}\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^\nu\right| 
&\le
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1} \left|\exp \left(\frac{z}{n}\right)^{n-1-\nu}  \left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^\nu \right|\\
&=
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1} \left|\exp \left(\frac{z}{n}\right)^{n-1-\nu} \right|  \left|1+\frac{z}{n}\right|^\nu \\
&\le
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1} \exp \left(\frac{|z|}{n}\right)^{n-1-\nu}  \left(1+\frac{|z|}{n}\right)^\nu \\
&\le
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1} \exp \left(\frac{|z|}{n}\right)^{n-1-\nu}  \exp\left(\frac{|z|}{n}\right)^\nu \\
&=
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1} \exp \left(\frac{|z|}{n}\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\exp \left(\frac{|z|}{n}\right)^{n-1}\\
&\le \exp|z|
\end{aligned}
$$
Here we use basic properties of complex modulus $|a+b|\le |a| + |b|$ and $|ab|=|a||b|$, as well as the easy inequalities $|\exp(z)| \le \exp|z|$ and $1+|z| \le \exp|z|$.
